# Open a new browser Window from a webview, without user input

Tags: webview, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal

I'm looking for a way to open a new browser window from a WebView, from a wp8.1 RT, silverlight or UWP app.

It should happen when the page loads, or after a few seconds, without any user input (I know it's possible if the user clicks on a 'target="_blank"' link)

Does anyone know if any way to do this exists?

I tried with `window.open`, jquery's `.click()` or `.submit()`, but nothing...

Neither the the javascript `alert()` works, it does work instead redirecting to a uri protocol with `location.href` and open an app, but unfortunately IE/Edge doesn't have an app protocol to launch it...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you put both Windows Phone 8 and Windows 10 in your tags, I can't be sure what to offer you here. SO I will tell you how to do it in 8.

JavaScript in a WebView can call external C# code by using ScriptNotify. You can read more about that in this question: [Call Native C# from WinJS that's loaded in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818314/call-native-c-sharp-from-winjs-thats-loaded-in-a-webview)

Also, once you are in C# and you want to launch a browser, the answer is to use the LaunchUriAsync API. Read more about that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx

Best of luck!